# Organize code in Node

Tags: node.js, require

I have a dir "model" and inside a few files (each for one model). Each of this files exportes a function:

```
module.exports = function (mongoose) {}
```

so I can call it from main file and pass a mongoose as argument:

```
require('./model/Mock_Models')(mongoose);
```

What is the best way to load all these models? Should I create models.js, in which I require manually each of these files, or maybe there is a shorter way, like just pointing a directory from which all files should be loaded with mongoose as argument?

Comment: There's [`require-all`](https://github.com/felixge/node-require-all).

Answer (score 0):

You can export them like so in an index.js inside your models directory:

```
export * from './mongoose';
```